# Returning value from gwt to javascript-jsni

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I am trying to return a value from java function in GWT to javascript via JSNI

```
    static public int call() { return 20; }

    public static native int jstest() /*-{
        try{
            val=@com.xxxx.package::call()();
            window.alert("Val:"+val);
            return $wnd.val;
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }-*/;
```

and in javascript `alert(document.val);`, I end up with Exception **Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method**. I guess I am messing up in returning value to javascript. Please let me know where I go wrong!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you declare `val` as global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring val as global it does get assigned on the window object (NOTE: not the $wnd objects). Sometimes with GWT those two are the same, sometimes they are not (it depends on the linker you are using).

This is why you need to change your code to read

```
$wnd.val = @com.xxxx.package::call()();
```

or remove the global variable with:

```
var val = @com.xxxx.package::call()();
return val;
```

Comment: and in plain javascript, i invoked alert(document.val);  ,but it did not return the value?,guess the call i made was not invoked properly !